# Django 1.9 deprecation warning when importing models in __init__.py

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I have shortcut function declared in __init__.py of my module in order to simplify importing it, ie.

```
from app.logger import log
```

instead of:

```
from app.logger.shortcuts import log
```

This function is a class object in principle, intendet to be used like singleton in this way:

```
# __init_.py
from app.logger.backends import LogDatabaseBackend
log = LogDatabaseBackend()
```

In the backends.py i need to import some models in this way:

```
# backends.py
from app.logger.models import Model1, Model2

class LogDatabaseBackend(object):
    ...
```

These models are necessary in some methods of LogDatabaseBackend. The problem is that Django show warnings like:

> "RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class app.logger.models.Model1 doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9."

I think the reason is importing model in init, before app was loaded. How should I change my code to avoid these warnings and maintain Django 1.9 compatibility?

Comment: you can set `app_label` in `Meta` of the `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

Define application configuration in `<app_name>.apps.py` :

**From [`Application Configuration`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#application-configuration) documentation :**

> Application configuration objects store metadata for an application.
>   Some attributes can be configured in AppConfig subclasses. Others are
>   set by Django and read-only.

**Here is an example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#for-application-authors) :**

```python
# rock_n_roll/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class RockNRollConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'rock_n_roll'
    verbose_name = "Rock ’n’ roll"
```

> You can make your application load this AppConfig subclass by default as
>   follows:

```python
# rock_n_roll/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'rock_n_roll.apps.RockNRollConfig'
```

> That will cause `RockNRollConfig` to be used when `INSTALLED_APPS` just
>   contains `'rock_n_roll'`. This allows you to make use of `AppConfig`
>   features without requiring your users to update their `INSTALLED_APPS`
>   setting. Besides this use case, it’s best to avoid using
>   `default_app_config` and instead specify the app config class in
>   `INSTALLED_APPS` as described next.

Comment: Thank you, it works on Django 1.8, although it seems to me like workaround and it is not completely DRY. Unfortunatelly, it does not work after Django upgrade to 1.9. I get **django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet** error, even if _app.logger.models_ (from example in my question) is totally empty.

Answer (score 0):

If `Model1` and `Model2` are used with `ForeignKey`, you don't need to import them. Instead use `ForeignKey("app.Model1", ...)`. This delays the import till after app registry. Otherwise, consider using function-level import.